# uncompyle6 Python3.9 not found

Tags: python, pip

I have tried to use uncompyle6 with python3.8 but every time I try to start it, it says:
`zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/uncompyle6: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory`
I don't have Python 3.9 installed

Im running MacOS 12.4 Beta (21F5058e) on an MacBook Air M1

my dc is Bwlok#6440

Comment: If you type `python --version` into the terminal, what do you get?

Comment: it says Python 3.8.9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.